# Left Join With COUNT()

Tags: t-sql

I have the following query that giving me issues on the second JOIN/COUNT for the  StatsStrategySessions table:

```
SELECT 
      fa.Id
    , CAST(fa.StatDate AS DATE)
    , COUNT(sa.CreatedDateTime) AS 'TotalApplications'
    , COUNT(ss.CreatedDateTime) AS 'TotalStrategySessions'
FROM StatsFacebookAds fa 
LEFT JOIN StatsApplications sa
ON CAST(fa.StatDate AS DATE) = CAST(sa.CreatedDateTime AS DATE)
AND sa.LeadSourceId = 1
LEFT JOIN StatsStrategySessions ss
ON CAST(fa.StatDate AS DATE) = CAST(ss.CreatedDateTime AS DATE)
AND ss.LeadSourceId = 1
GROUP BY      
      fa.Id
    , fa.StatDate
```

It returns twice the amount that it should...

It returns...

```
  Id                     TotalApplications TotalStrategySessions
    ----------- ---------- ----------------- ---------------------
    1           2019-12-02 1                 1
    2           2019-12-03 0                 0
    3           2019-12-04 0                 0
    4           2019-12-05 4                 4
```

With the second JOIN/COUNT doubles to 4 instead of what should be 2.

When I run the code without the second JOIN/COUNT it returns as expected.

The code works as I would expect it to.

```
SELECT 
      fa.Id
    , CAST(fa.StatDate AS DATE)
    , COUNT(sa.CreatedDateTime) AS 'TotalApplications'
FROM StatsFacebookAds fa 
LEFT JOIN StatsApplications sa
ON CAST(fa.StatDate AS DATE) = CAST(sa.CreatedDateTime AS DATE)
AND sa.LeadSourceId = 1
GROUP BY      
      fa.Id
    , fa.StatDate
```

It returns what I expect it to...

```
Id                     TotalApplications
----------- ---------- -----------------
1           2019-12-02 1
2           2019-12-03 0
3           2019-12-04 0
4           2019-12-05 2
```

But as soon as I join the second table the numbers are not what I'm trying to display.

It's been a while since I wrote tsql so hopefully it some I space on...

Thanks for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a distinct count on the `StatsApplications` table:

```
SELECT
    fa.Id,
    CAST(fa.StatDate AS DATE),
    COUNT(DISTINCT sa.CreatedDateTime) AS [TotalApplications],  -- change is here
    COUNT(ss.CreatedDateTime) AS [TotalStrategySessions]
FROM StatsFacebookAds fa
LEFT JOIN StatsApplications sa
    ON CAST(fa.StatDate AS DATE) = CAST(sa.CreatedDateTime AS DATE) AND
       sa.LeadSourceId = 1
LEFT JOIN StatsStrategySessions ss
    ON CAST(fa.StatDate AS DATE) = CAST(ss.CreatedDateTime AS DATE) AND
       ss.LeadSourceId = 1
GROUP BY
    fa.Id,
    fa.StatDate;
```

The concept here is that the second additional join to the `StatsStrategySessions` table runs the risk of duplicating all the records in the `StatsApplications` table, since each latter record might join to multiple records in the former.  But, by taking the distinct count, we can remove the double counting.

If you don't like this approach, then another way to handle this would be to join to a subquery on the two tables which finds the counts separately, and then join back to `StatsFacebookAds`.